# Getting correct XPATH expression for DIV CLASS

Tags: c#, xpath

i am trying to traverse an html document:

```
<body class="style_0">
        <div>
            <div class="style_1">Pending Test List</div>
            <table style=" width: 100%;" id="AUTOGENBOOKMARK_4365445353431356880">
                <col>
                <col>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_4">Pending Test List</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_5">SOME AGENCY Laboratories, Inc.</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <table class="style_6" style=" width: 4.531in;" id="AUTOGENBOOKMARK_5083738604442918131">
                <col style=" width: 1in;">
                <col class="style_7" style=" width: 0.75in;">
                <col class="style_8" style=" width: 0.6in;">
                <col style=" width: 0.75in;">
                <col style=" width: 2.375in;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="style_9" style=" height: 0.5in;">
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                            <div class="style_10">Report Range:</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                            <div class="style_11">01/01/2012</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                            <div class="style_12">through</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                            <div class="style_13">01/31/2012</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                            <div class="style_14">(by Date Entered)</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <table class="style_15" style=" width: 100%;" id="AUTOGENBOOKMARK_7602283385844673591" iid="/526

(QuRs78576248:0)">
                <col style=" width: 0.75in;">
                <col style=" width: 1.25in;">
                <col style=" width: 1in;">
                <col style=" width: 1.5in;">
                <col style=" width: 1.5in;">
                <col style=" width: 1.5in;">
                <col>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4" style="vertical-align: baseline;"></td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"></td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"></td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_16">Entered</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_16">Spec. ID</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_16">Batch/Pos.</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_16">Test</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_16">Client ID</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_16">Client Name</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_16">Agency</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_18">1/30/12</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_19">ZZ324sdf</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_18">51446 / 75</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">HOLD_DE</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">234234</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">smith, john</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">PPPM-6P - SOME AGENCY</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_18">1/31/12</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_19">SFD3434</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_18">51668 / 17</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">HOLD_DE</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">FOY, EL</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">FOY, ALEX</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">someagency &amp; Associates LLC</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_18">1/31/12</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_19">SFD3434</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_18">51668 / 25</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">HOLD_DE</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">JAMISON, PA</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">JAMISON, ROY</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">someagency &amp; Associates LLC</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_18">1/31/12</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_19">SFD3434</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_18">51669 / 34</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">HOLD_DE</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">NEWMAN, SO</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">NEWMAN, ALEX</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style_17" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_20">someagency &amp; Associates LLC</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_21">Total Tests:</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_22">4</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"></td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"></td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"></td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
            <table style=" width: 100%;" id="AUTOGENBOOKMARK_8507236727661888074">
                <col>
                <col>
                <col>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_2">
                                <br>Feb 13, 2012 9:37 AM</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;">
                            <div class="style_3">
                                <br>
                                <div style="text-align:center;">Page 1</div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: baseline;"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
```

for this data:

[image]

so far i have this:

```
foreach (var row in htmlSnippet.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class = 'style_15']/tbody/tr"))
                {
                    foreach (var cell in row.SelectNodes("div[@class='*']"))
                    {
                        textBox1.Text = cell.InnerHtml.ToString();
                    }
                }
```

however i am not returning anything!

this line is working:

```
//table[@class = 'style_15']/tbody/tr
```

but this does not return anthing:

```
("div[@class='*']"))
```

please let me know what i am doing wrong! i need help returning every piece of data as shown in the image (except for the field names)

Comment: You seems to have skipped td ... row.SelectNodes("td/div[@class='*']")

Comment: @amit_g thank you for your help, that did not work

Comment: @patrick im sorry neither of those worked. it goes FINE through the outer loop with //table.... but never goes into the inner loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want simply `div[@class]`—a `div` element that has a `class` attribute.

Oh, it's also worth noting that the HTML/XML sample you provided is *not well-formed*.  I had to remove all the `col` elements, and close the `br` elements.  Maybe, for C#, that's an issue... I know it is for XSL in general... not sure about XPath.

I don't have time to code up a C# example, but here's a simple XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <so>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//table[@class = 'style_15']/tbody/tr"/>
  </so>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="div[@class]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

I get this output:

```
<so>
  <div class="style_18">1/30/12</div>
  <div class="style_19">ZZ324sdf</div>
  <div class="style_18">51446 / 75</div>
  <div class="style_20">HOLD_DE</div>
  <div class="style_20">234234</div>
  <div class="style_20">smith, john</div>
  <div class="style_20">PPPM-6P - SOME AGENCY</div>
  <div class="style_18">1/31/12</div>
  <div class="style_19">SFD3434</div>
  <div class="style_18">51668 / 17</div>
  <div class="style_20">HOLD_DE</div>
  <div class="style_20">FOY, EL</div>
  <div class="style_20">FOY, ALEX</div>
  <div class="style_20">someagency &amp; Associates LLC</div>
  <div class="style_18">1/31/12</div>
  <div class="style_19">SFD3434</div>
  <div class="style_18">51668 / 25</div>
  <div class="style_20">HOLD_DE</div>
  <div class="style_20">JAMISON, PA</div>
  <div class="style_20">JAMISON, ROY</div>
  <div class="style_20">someagency &amp; Associates LLC</div>
  <div class="style_18">1/31/12</div>
  <div class="style_19">SFD3434</div>
  <div class="style_18">51669 / 34</div>
  <div class="style_20">HOLD_DE</div>
  <div class="style_20">NEWMAN, SO</div>
  <div class="style_20">NEWMAN, ALEX</div>
  <div class="style_20">someagency &amp; Associates LLC</div>
</so>
```

This is just an intermediate output to show that the XPath is working correctly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

The `*` is typically used for matching any element or attribute *name*, not any *value*. If you want to match all `div` elements having a `class` attribute with any value, just use `@class`.

```
foreach (var row in htmlSnippet.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class = 'style_15']/tbody/tr/td"))
{
    foreach (var cell in row.SelectNodes("div[@class]"))
    {
        textBox1.Text = cell.InnerHtml.ToString();
    }
}
```